# Xcode cannot set UITextField auto capitalisation

Tags: xcode, uitextfield, uppercase, autocorrect

Few months ago, I work on project and success to set text field auto capitalisation.

However when I reopen it and it cannot upper case text I input.

I don't know what happen. Here is my code:

```
myTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeDefault;
myTextField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords // or use UITextAutocapitalizationTypeAllCharacters;
```

Any solution will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I hope you are not using Mac keyboard to type on simulator.

Comment: I deploy in iPhone to test app.

Comment: And on iPhone device, Settings > General > Keyboard > Auto-Capitalisation is not switched off, right?

Comment: Opps, you right. But what happen if user turn auto-capitalization off?

Comment: I think, they are global settings. So, if it's off, auto-capitalization feature doesn't work on that device.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there are two possibilities for auto-capitalization not to work when every code that you wrote looks good.

- When running your app on iPhone Simulator, make sure that you use
  simulator's keyboard; not Mac keyboard.
- When the app is running on device, make sure `Settings >> General >>
  Keyboard >> Auto-Capitalisation` is not switched off. A global setting.

Comment: Is there any ways that notice user to turn on Auto-Capitalisation when they first start app?

Comment: Try `myTextField.autocorrectionType=UITextAutocorrectionTypeYes;` Seems like auto-correction affects auto-capitalization. Turning on auto-capitalization programmatically should probably be another question.